# How to Enable Auto Enter (After Scan) on Honeywell CK65

Tags: android, xml, mdm, honeywell

I need to edit Suffix and Wedge as keys value for multiple handheld scanners (HK65).
My thought was to push an xml file to all scanners through our MDM platform. Im not entirely sure which path to use for this or if I somewhere have to force devices to make use of the xml file. Hoping someone can share their ideas with me.

This is what i'm trying to archive:
https://www.libertysystems.com/about/resources/auto-enter-after-scan-for-honeywell-mobile-computers/